# Correct syntax to use with Click Button

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm writing a robot framework/Selenium test script to validate the login process for a web site.  I'm unable to get the correct syntax to automate the press of the Login button.  Here is the robot script:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Project Automated Test
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${LOGIN URL}      http://localhost/project
${BROWSER}        Chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Maximize Browser Window
    Welcome Page Should Be Open
    Login_User
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}

Welcome Page Should Be Open
    Page should contain  Project Tasks

Login_User
    Click Button  Login
```

Here is the code for the Login button:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="
                if(document.getElementById('authentication').style.display == 'none'){
                    $('#authentication').slideDown('slow');
                                    } else {
                    $('#authentication').slideUp('slow');
                }
                " href="#" value="Login">
```

When the script starts Chrome opens up and the web page is displayed correctly.  I can see the Login button on the web page.  I've tried various combinations for the Click Button locator parameter (Login, value=Login, text=Login).  Every attempt results in a Button with locator not found message.  This is my first project with Robot Framework/Selenium so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Third` parameter is your `locator` you can use id,name,xpath or css selector.since id and name is NOT available you can use xpath or css selector.

```
 Login_User
        Click Button  xpath://input[@class='btn'][@value='Login']
```

OR css Selector

```
Login_User
        Click Button  css:input.btn[value='Login']
```

You can refer following [robot framework](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html) documentation.

Comment: None of the three recommendations appear to work for me:  Click Button  "//input[@class='btn'][@value='Login']"

Button with locator '"//input[@class='btn'][@value='Login']"' not found.

Click Button  xpath="//input[@class='btn'][@value='Login']"

InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "//input[@class='btn'][@value='Login']" because of the following error:

Click Button  css="input.btn[value='Login']"

InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: My mistake put `=` instead of `:` try now

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to use click button in robot framework.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Basic Search Functionality

Library  SeleniumLibrary

***test cases ***
Press Keys   locater_here-button Xpath   ENTER
```

It will work